# Moving table from on prem to azure table storage

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I thought this would be relatively simple - but i can’t figure out the issue.

I’m trying to copy tables from on prem to azure table storage in datalake.

During the copy activity I can preview my source data which looks well and good, I’m also using a custom partition key.

During sink - I have created a dataset in table store (all connections are fine) , but I cannot preview my data no map it and neither can I import the schemas.

I’m not sure what I’m doing wrong. Pls help.

Comment: This is difficult to troubleshoot, we cannot see your configuration. Can you share the JSON configuration and hide any sensitive information?

Answer (score 0):

I created table in Table Storage. I simply added Source and Sink.

Source Schema

[image]

Below was my configuration in Sink.

[image]

I was able to import schema, as shown in below screenshot.

Here you can do mapping after providing **PartitionKey** and **RowKey**.

[image]